# pgffor map elements

Tags: pgf-core

pgffor's foreach can take an "array" of elements. I need to map those elements using another array(a lookup table) because I need both the elements and there mapped value.

e.g., suppose I an doing some cryptography and have letters mapped to numbers in some non-standard way

```
\foreach \i in {a,b,c,d,e}
{
 \i = \lookup{\i}{\data}
}
```

where data is, I guess some type of associative array that says stuff like

```
a = 12, b = 16, c = 3, d = 9, e = 19
```

which the foreach will then print

```
a = 12
b = 16
c = 3
d = 9
e = 19
```

I also can simply another array and I want to step through them simultanously, for of like

```
\foreach \i,\j in {a,b,c,d,e} , {12,16,3,9,19}
{
 \i = \j
}
```

(I do not want some type of nested loops, that is not what I'm trying to do)

The easiest solution the better. I'm not trying to do anything extremely complex

Comment: Don't forget to indent your code by 4 spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the question, you have some options in mind and things you might not do but the question is not clear at all. I'm guessing something of the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor,pgfmath}

% Got some array from Excel via =randbetween(1-26)
\def\Sometwentysixnumarray{{11,4,8,12,17,20,13,9,12,16,4,19,6,11,4,26,10,13,14,15,15,1,5,1,26,14}}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x[count=\xi from 0] in {a,...,z}{
\pgfmathparse{\Sometwentysixnumarray[\xi]}
\x = \pgfmathresult, 
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks like it will work. It's very simple, I want to map the index value into another value. It would be nice if I could simply define what you have done in my last example as it is cleaner but yours achieves the same thing as far as I can tell.

Comment: @AbstractDissonance I'm sorry but I don't understand your comment. Why don't you state the problem clearly with actual data with a minimal example giving the exact output you wish to obtain so that we don't guess each others intention?

Comment: lol, you seem to be the only one confused ;/

Comment: @AbstractDissonance That might be true.